# Unable to test react component with using some mocked functions

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

Hi I am trying to test this react component, for some weird reasons I can test that the mocked function `login` was called however the test keeps failing saying the other mocked function `proceed` is not called. I tried to console log something from the `proceed` function and it works. So i don't know what the problem is

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import axios from 'axios';
import notifier from 'simple-react-notifications'

class EnrollLoginForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoggingIn: false,
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.setState({
          isLoggingIn: true
        })

        this.props.login(values).then((res) => {
      console.log(res, 'jsdskdsdk')
      notifier.success(res.message)
      this.props.proceed()
    }).catch((err) => {
      notifier.error('ERROR! Unable to authenticate!')
      const errors = err.response.data.errors || {}
      this.props.form.setFields({
        email: {
          errors: errors.email ? [new Error(errors.email[0])] : [],
        },
        password: {
          errors: errors.password ? [new Error(errors.password[0])] : [],
        },
      })
    }).finally(() => {
      if (this.state.mounted) {
        this.setState({
          isLoggingIn: false
        })
      }
    })
      }
    })
    // this.props.proceed()
  };

  render () {
    const { form } = this.props
    const { getFieldDecorator } = form
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="enroll-register-form">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <Form.Item>
              <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
              {getFieldDecorator('email', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your email!' }],
              })(
                <Input
                  size="large"
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="jonathanadamu@mymail.com"
                />,
              )}
            </Form.Item>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <Form.Item>
              <label htmlFor="password">
                Password
              </label>
              {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
              })(
                <Input.Password
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Enter your password"
                />,
              )}
            </Form.Item>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Form.Item className="is-full-width">
          <Button
            disabled={this.state.isLoggingIn}
            loading={this.state.isLoggingIn}
            htmlType="submit"
            size="large"
            type="danger"
          >
            Proceed
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}

EnrollLoginForm.propTypes = {
  form: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  proceed: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const WrappedEnrollLoginForm = Form.create({
  name: 'enroll login form'
})(EnrollLoginForm)

export default WrappedEnrollLoginForm
```

// TEST FILE

```
describe ('login', () => {
   it ('logins in a user', () => {
        const login = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({f: 2893}))
        const proceed = jest.fn(() => {
            console.log('sdhjs')
        })
        const payload = {
            email: 'ewomaukah@yahoo.com',
            password: 'solomon1'
        }
        const wrapper = mount(
            <EnrollLoginForm 
                proceed={proceed}
                login={login}
            />
        )
        wrapper.find('input[type="email"]').simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: payload.email
            }
        })
        wrapper.find('input[type="password"]').simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: payload.password
            }
        })
        wrapper.find('Form').simulate('submit')
        expect(wrapper.find('.ant-form-explain').length).toEqual(0);
        expect(login).toBeCalledWith(payload)
        expect(proceed).toBeCalled()
    });

})
```

Please someone should put me in the right direction, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proceed is supposed to be called in the **then** block of the **login** function. I think the test is failing because the login promise has not been resolved by the time you check if **proceed** is called.

Try to make the test asynchronous and await the submit event like this:

```js
it ('logins in a user', async () => {
        const login = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({f: 2893}))
        const proceed = jest.fn(() => {
            console.log('sdhjs')
        })
        const payload = {
            email: 'ewomaukah@yahoo.com',
            password: 'solomon1'
        }
        const wrapper = mount(
            <EnrollLoginForm 
                proceed={proceed}
                login={login}
            />
        )
        wrapper.find('input[type="email"]').simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: payload.email
            }
        })
        wrapper.find('input[type="password"]').simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: payload.password
            }
        })
        await wrapper.find('Form').simulate('submit')
        expect(wrapper.find('.ant-form-explain').length).toEqual(0);
        expect(login).toBeCalledWith(payload)
        expect(proceed).toBeCalled()
    });
```

Comment: thank you so much @jacksonk.dev. That solved my issue.